# Grid.MVC Sorting Bug

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting, grid.mvc

Grid.MVC sorting not working as expected. For example I have a column with a number value and also date values. The screen shots provided show only the Total Premium sort not working right, but the same thing happens on the Effective Date Column as well. Is there something additional I need to do to tell it its a number or date so it sorts correctly?

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResult).Named("searchGrid").Columns(col =>
{
col.Add(c => c.PolicyNumber).Titled("Number").Sortable(true);
col.Add(c => c.FormattedInsuredName).Titled("Insured Name").Sortable(true);
col.Add(c => c.FormattedAddress).RenderValueAs(m => Html.Raw(m.FormattedAddress)).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("Property Address").Sortable(true);
col.Add(c => c.Status).Titled("Status").Sortable(true);
col.Add(c => c.FormattedEffectiveDate).Titled("Effective Date").Sortable(true);
col.Add(c => c.FormattedTotalPremium).Titled("Total Premium").Sortable(true);
col.Add().Encoded(false).SetWidth(150).Sanitized(false).Titled("Action").RenderValueAs(dd => Html.DropDownList("ddlAction", dd.DropDownActions, new { @class = "form-control ddlAction", @data_viewquote = dd.QuoteURL }));
}).WithPaging(25).Sortable(true)
```

From the screen shot below you can see that the Total Premium column is being sorted incorrectly. There are screen shots for both ASC and DESC.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're sorting them as strings instead as integers; They're sorting alphabetically, which is why 1226 would come before 223. You'll need to convert them to an integer prior to sorting. I apologize for not providing the exact method for this, I'm not very familiar with MVC - just figured this would point you in the right direction.

Comment: Just to remark on my previous comment, the same goes for dates. You'll need to convert them to their respective type.

Comment: Well that was simple.  The columns were being formatted to strings from their initial types.  Got that figured out and it now sorts correctly. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: No problem, I've been burned on the same issue!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Santi for the comment.

The type for the model was being formatted to a string to show a certain format before it got to the grid.  Removed the string formatting and put the formatting up at the grid to allow sorting on the proper type and still show formatting.  New grid below with the additional .Format() pieces.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.SearchResult).Named("searchGrid").Columns(col =>
{
   col.Add(c => c.PolicyNumber).Titled("Number").Sortable(true);
   col.Add(c => c.FormattedInsuredName).Titled("Insured Name").Sortable(true);
   col.Add(c => c.FormattedAddress).RenderValueAs(m => Html.Raw(m.FormattedAddress)).Encoded(false).Sanitized(false).Titled("Property Address").Sortable(true);
   col.Add(c => c.Status).Titled("Status").Sortable(true);
   col.Add(c => c.FormattedEffectiveDate).Titled("Effective Date").Sortable(true).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
   col.Add(c => c.FormattedTotalPremium).Titled("Total Premium").Sortable(true).Format("{0:C2}");
   col.Add().Encoded(false).SetWidth(150).Sanitized(false).Titled("Action").RenderValueAs(dd => Html.DropDownList("ddlAction", dd.DropDownActions, new { @class = "form-control ddlAction", @data_viewquote = dd.QuoteURL }));
}).WithPaging(25).Sortable(true)
```